# Why is Python loading numpy 1.20.0 in my dask env when conda says 1.20.1 is installed?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, conda

Why is Python loading numpy 1.20.0 in my dask env when conda says 1.20.1 is installed?

```
(dask) ➜  dask: conda list -n dask | grep numpy
numpy                     1.20.1           py38h18fd61f_0    conda-forge

(dask) ➜  dask: python
Python 3.8.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 20 2021, 16:22:27) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.full_version
'1.20.0'
```

Comment: The user site (e.g. `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` on linux for 3.8) has precedence over the conda packages. Did you pip install numpy to that location? You can check with `numpy.__file__`

Comment: That's appears to be the reason then. I'm still surprised by this behaviour. After all virtual environments serve the purpose of preventing precisely that - at least that's what I thought. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen because by default, python packages installed in the so-called user site (`pip install --user package` or in newer pip versions automatically when the prefix directory is not writable for the current user) are still considered first in the `PYTHONPATH`.

You can deactivate the user site using three methods:

- `-s` command line option for python: `python -s -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)'`
- the `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` environment variable: `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` (the actual value does not matter, just that it is set) and then `python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)'`
- In your script, before importing anything, do

  ```
  import site
  site.ENABLE_USER_SITE = False
  ```

I would go for one of the first two, things like these shouldn't be inside scripts but solved by the environment.

To get the location of your user site, you can do:

```
python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_SITE)'
```

Comment: is this because conda is supposed to integrate with pip?

Comment: No, this is rather independent from pip. Python looks into the user site by default. It does not matter how packages end up there (you could put files manually there or run `python setup.py install --user` for a package or ...).

Comment: would you say that my issue described here stems from a flawed setup (my fault) or from conda being flawed at insulating venvs? because I just took it for granted that when I run python in a (conda or pip) venv that it will only use those packages installed in the venv and nothing else.

Comment: You could argue, that it might make sense for conda to `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` when activating a conda environment. But I doubt they will implement this, since it is probably a huge breaking change in behaviour.

Comment: For what it's worth: the python `venv` module by the way ignores the user site packages by default.

Comment: This was discussed here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/394